# How can I get data from a dynamic page without using slowMo?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer, steam

I made a code to get Steam data, specifically the game title and price. Here is the code:

```
async function handleAgeRestriction(p) {
  await p.evaluate(() => {
    const select = document.querySelector("#ageYear");
    const options = select.querySelectorAll("option");
    const selectedOption = [...options].find(
      (option) => option.text === "1900"
    );

    selectedOption.selected = true;
  });
  await p.click("#view_product_page_btn");
}


async function getDataFromGame() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(
    "https://store.steampowered.com/app/221100/"
  );

  await handleAgeRestriction(page);

  const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const title = document.querySelector(".apphub_AppName").innerText;
    const price = document.querySelector('.game_purchase_price').innerText;
    const bundle_title = document.querySelector('div.game_area_purchase_game > h1').innerText;
    const bundle_price = document.querySelector('.discount_final_price').innerText;

    const game = {
      title,
      price,
      bundle_title,
      bundle_price
    }
    return game;
  });

  console.log(result);

  await browser.close();
}
```

When I run it, I get this error:

**node:internal/process/promises:279
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^

Error [TypeError]: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerText')
at evaluate**

This is what I tried and it worked

```
async function getDataFromGame() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 1000 });
```

The issue is that it takes a long time to retrieve the data and I wouldn't want someone who wants to use my code to have to see the entire functionality.

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. What is `handleAgeRestriction`? As for your error, the typical solution is using `waitForSelector` on each of the elements you're querying, rather than sleeping, which is effectively what `slowMo: 1000` does. Once `waitForSelector()` resolves, then it's safe to `evaluate()`.

Comment: This is the missing code sorry: async function handleAgeRestriction(p) {
  await p.evaluate(() => {
    const select = document.querySelector("#ageYear");
    const options = select.querySelectorAll("option");
    const selectedOption = [...options].find(
      (option) => option.text === "1900"
    );

    selectedOption.selected = true;
  });
  await p.click("#view_product_page_btn");
}

I'm not sure what waitForSelector would be used for. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: Please [edit] the post to add code. `waitForSelector` is used to wait for a selector. That sounds tautological, but I'm not sure how else to describe it. Your queries are returning `null` because the page hasn't rendered the element matching the CSS selector, which is why your `evaluate` function is crashing. So wait for those selectors first so the query doesn't fail: `await page.waitForSelector(".apphub_AppName");` (repeat for all of your selectors). Once all those lines resolve, go ahead and query with `evaluate`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. I don't know how to upvote your response, even though my question was basic haha.

Comment: Glad it worked and it's OK if it's basic, although if you search the error this is a common thread so you can get the answer much quicker: [Javascript Cannot read property 'innerText' of null - puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59340100/javascript-cannot-read-property-innertext-of-null-puppeteer). Your question is probably better since you've shown a simpler, more reproducible example of it.